# Entity Framework updating property of another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 3 entities Order, Item and Seller. In my Order Controller I'm trying to get the Item List and the quantity that was sent in the Request.

Order Entity:

```
public class Order
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    public long SellerId { get; set; }
    public Seller Seller { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Item Entity:

```
public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Skuid { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller with the Post method where I'm trying to get the Items and the amount and save it in a List to save it in the Database. In this case, I am managing to carry out the request, but the total quantity of the Item is saved in this Item List and not the quantity that was sent in the request.

```
[HttpPost("v1/order")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrderAsync(
    [FromServices] PottencialDataContext context,
    [FromBody] CreateOrderViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(new ResultViewModel<string>(ModelState.GetErrors()));
    
    try
    {
        var listItem = new List<Item>();
        double total = 0;
        
        foreach (var item in model.Items)
        {
            var itemSkuid = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Skuid == item.Skuid);
            itemSkuid.Amount -= item.Amount; 
            context.Items.Update(itemSkuid);
            
            total = TotalPriceOrder.OrderTotalPrice(listItem, item.Amount);
            listItem.Add(itemSkuid);
        }

        var seller = await context.Sellers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == model.SellerId);
        if (seller == null)
            return NotFound(new ResultViewModel<Seller>("Not Found"));

        var newOrder = new Order
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Status = StatusEnum.AWAITING_PAYMENT,
            Seller = seller,
            Total = total,
            Items = listItem
        };

        await context.Orders.AddAsync(newOrder);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created($"v1/order/{newOrder.Id}", new ResultViewModel<Order>(newOrder));
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new ResultViewModel<Seller>("WM0X23"));
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new ResultViewModel<Seller>("WM0X24"));
    }
}
```

So I added this other ForEach to update the value of the Items in the List, but for some reason it updates the value of the Item saved in the database that is in another table, and I didn't understand why:

```
[HttpPost("v1/order")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrderAsync(
    [FromServices] PottencialDataContext context,
    [FromBody] CreateOrderViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(new ResultViewModel<string>(ModelState.GetErrors()));
    
    try
    {
        var listItem = new List<Item>();
        double total = 0;
        
        foreach (var item in model.Items)
        {
            var itemSkuid = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Skuid == item.Skuid);
            itemSkuid.Amount -= item.Amount; 
            context.Items.Update(itemSkuid);
            
            total = TotalPriceOrder.OrderTotalPrice(listItem, item.Amount);
            listItem.Add(itemSkuid);
        }
        



        **//NEW FOREACH TO DEFINE THE VALUE OF THE ITEMS IN THE LIST**

        foreach (var item in listItem)
        {
            foreach (var amountItem in model.Items)
            {
                var amount = amountItem.Amount;
                item.Amount = amount;
            }
        }

        var seller = await context.Sellers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == model.SellerId);
        if (seller == null)
            return NotFound(new ResultViewModel<Seller>("Not Found"));

        var newOrder = new Order
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Status = StatusEnum.AWAITING_PAYMENT,
            Seller = seller,
            Total = total,
            Items = listItem
        };

        await context.Orders.AddAsync(newOrder);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created($"v1/order/{newOrder.Id}", new ResultViewModel<Order>(newOrder));
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new ResultViewModel<Seller>("WM0X23"));
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new ResultViewModel<Seller>("WM0X24"));
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this logic?

Comment: You cannot use items as details of new Order returned by EF. You should create new instances.

Answer (score 1):

Update code inside `foreach` like this and try,

```
foreach (var item in model.Items)
{
    var itemSkuid = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Skuid == item.Skuid);
    itemSkuid.Amount -= item.Amount; 
    context.Items.Update(itemSkuid);
    
    var itemObj = new Item
    {
        Id = itemSkuid.Id,
        Name = itemSkuid.Name,
        Skuid = itemSkuid.Skuid,
        Price = itemSkuid.Price,
        Amount = item.Amount
    };

    total = TotalPriceOrder.OrderTotalPrice(listItem, item.Amount);
    listItem.Add(itemObj);
}
```

Comment: I tried the modifications but an error appeared = "The instance of entity type 'Item' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

Comment: @wesleymoreira, do not call `Update` - it is a problem.  EF Core will update entity anyway.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I removed Update and the error continues

Comment: I discovered the problem, in "itemObj" I removed the Id attribute because the database already generates it automatically, but now it creates a new Item in every new request!

Comment: @wesleymoreira means is there any issue still? or all sorted?

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi Now there is no error, the problem is that with each new request a new Item of "itemObj" is created and saved in the database as a new Item